# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/MessengerCompat

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, cross-platform

So I've searched a lot on the internet already on what the error is causing me, and they are all saying that a library has been duplicated.  For this case I'm not sure which library, I'm looking at my references and seeing no duplicate this is what's inside my reference.
[image: References]

BTW I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community and my project is Xamarin Cross-Platform.

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same error when adding this plugin : [Xam.Plugin.PushNotification](https://github.com/rdelrosario/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/PushNotification)
To resolve this error, what I did was :
Remove the plugin and all its dependencies entirely, for me that meant removing Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm and Iid too.

Then I added Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Iid version 32.961.0

Then I added Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm version 32.961.0

Then I added the Push plugin. Currently it seems as if the build error has gone away. Fingers crossed the push code will work too.

Answer (score -3):

I have had this problem before, I solved it by removing Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, and after that cleaning the solution.

Comment: How did you remove the Android.Support.v4 without having to remove Xamarin.forms ? I get an error saying that the Xamarin.Forms depends on v4 so it cannot be removed.