# IllegalArgument Exception already added MessengerCompat

Tags: java, android, xamarin, push-notification, onesignal

I'm doing a Xamarin Cross Platform App. I add the nuget package "OneSignal" to get Push Notification.

I follow all the steps on the next tutorial:

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/testing-mobile-push-notifications

And when I try to compile the project, I have this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :  Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/MessengerCompat;
```

If I go to the exception, it gives me to the "Xamarin.Android.Common.targets" file, to this line:

```
<!-- Compile java code to dalvik -->
<CompileToDalvik 
DxJarPath="$(DxJarPath)"
DxExtraArguments="$(DxExtraArguments)"
JavaToolPath="$(JavaToolPath)"
JavaMaximumHeapSize="$(JavaMaximumHeapSize)"
JavaOptions="$(JavaOptions)"
ClassesOutputDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)android\bin\classes"
ToolPath="$(DxToolPath)"
ToolExe="$(DxToolExe)"
UseDx="$(UseDx)"
MultiDexEnabled="$(AndroidEnableMultiDex)"
MultiDexMainDexListFile="$(_AndroidMainDexListFile)"
JavaLibrariesToCompile="@(_JavaLibrariesToCompileForAppDx)"
OptionalObfuscatedJarFile="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\__proguard_output__.jar"
/>
```

I try this solution, but it doesn't work for me, it gives me more exceptions with objects that it doesn't found when I uninstall the Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.

[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/MessengerCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622571/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-already-added-lcom-google-android-gms-iid-m)

Can anyone help me? I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: edited with more info

Comment: You will need to look at your overall dependencies in your project. This error message is letting you know that you have dependencies that are including the same class twice. This could be related to the [Support v4 library splitting](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#v4). You should ensure that all of your Support Library versions are the same in your project.

Comment: I remove the Android.Support.v4 and all the others Android.Support and I still have the same error. I try removing also the maps and geolocator nuget package, but it gives me the same exception. Only when I remove oneSignal nuget package I can compile correctly... Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Tray Install **"Xamarin.googleplayservices.Gcm"**

It's Work for me!

Comment: What do ads have to do with push notifications?

Comment: you were right just need a plugin. I edited the comment!