# C# Xamarin Convert array to float

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, parsing, xamarin.android

I have an array with prices. Now I created a foreach like this:

```
var singleNameWithOldestPrice =
    from p in PriceList
    where p.NAME.Contains(SelectedProduct, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    group p by p.NAME into grp
    select grp.OrderBy(a => a.TIMESTAMP).ToArray();

foreach (var p in singleNameWithOldestPrice)
{
    source.Add(new Entry(p)
    {
        Label = "Name",
        ValueLabel = float.Parse(p),
        Color = SKColor.Parse("#f79c00")
    });
}
```

Now the code crashes in this part at the first p:

```
source.Add(new Entry(p)
{
    Label = "Name",
    ValueLabel = p.ToString(),
    Color = SKColor.Parse("#f79c00")
});
```

The first p in "new Entry(p)" must be a float, because the error is:

"Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'projectname.price[]' to 'float'"

What can I do???

Comment: can you debug and check what is the data type of p? Seems to me that it's an array(`projectname.price[]`)? That's why it's throwing an error. It would also help if you can post the class structure of PriceList.

Comment: What means this error: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :  Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;"

Comment: Is that related to the above question? You might want to post a different question for that or check this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622571/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-already-added-lcom-google-android-gms-iid-m

Comment: Please post the model of PriceList, Price, and Entry. Without them, we can't answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `group p by p.NAME into grp`. So the `p` is an array of your price object.
If you want to get the float value in the `price`, your need another `foreach`.

For example:

```
            foreach (var p in singleNameWithOldestPrice)
            {
                foreach (var pp in p)
                {
                    source.Add(new Entry(pp.price)
                    {
                        Label = "Name",
                        ValueLabel = pp.price.ToString(),
                        Color = SKColor.Parse("#f79c00")
                    });
                }
            }
```

Comment: @A. Vreeswijk Does it help you to solve your problem?